# How to issue and customize .htaccess for Laravel?

Tags: php, apache, laravel, .htaccess, laravel-5.3

I have just launched a Laravel 5.3 project on a live server and all is going well except one.

But my issue is, My websites are running on all 3 different URL.

My server is **Ubuntu 16.4.**

1. website.com
2. website.com/public/index.php
3. website.com/ any word /index.php

My `.htaccess` is: (This file is in the root folder)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

But I just want to see my website with `website.com` URL only.

Comment: hi is you want to remove /public form your website... ?

Comment: Hi, correct me if Im wrong. You want all your urls served from example.com instead of www.example.com. and all urls other than those ending with /index.php to be redirected to example.com?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like your Laravel app is accesible via an Apache HTTP alias. Follow these steps

Try to navigate to your expected route prepend it with `/index.php/`, in your case: `website.com/index.php/users`. If it works (no 404) then you problem is with the Rewrite Module configuration of Apache HTTP, you should follow the next steps.

Edit the file public/.htaccess.

Under the line `RewriteEngine On` add `RewriteBase /` if files are on root directory if in folder like `laravel` then add `RewriteBase /laravel/`

Try to navigate to an existing route.

i.e

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**Remove /public from your Laravel**
create a virtual host

go to  `/etc/apache2/sites-available` create .conf file or update 000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin admin@example.com
   ServerName website.com
  ServerAlias www.website.com

DocumentRoot /var/www/html/index.html

        <Directory /var/www/html/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>


        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =website.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.website.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for help me, I add `RewriteBase /` in `.htaccess` file in root folder and public folder. Only this where true: `website.com/ any word /index.php` and now i can open website with `website.com/public/index.php` :-(

Comment: @mySun is it working fine now.. are you still have problem ..?

Comment: My example code is in `.htaccess` file in root project. Now Under the line `RewriteEngine On` add `RewriteBase /` in the file `public/.htaccess.`. but i can see my website with `website.com/public/index.php` and `website.com/public`.

Answer (score 2):

**1. I understand why you are trying to change the .htaccess but this can be solved alot simpler. Revert the .htaccess file back to the Laravel standard**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**2. Move all of your folders and files apart from public and make sure they are behind your HTML folder.**

**3. Move all of your public folders and files out of the public folder and into your html folder**

**4. Tell laravel to look in your html folder instead of public by altering the server.php file**

```
<?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylorotwell@gmail.com>
 */

$uri = urldecode(
    parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)
);

// This file allows us to emulate Apache's "mod_rewrite" functionality from the
// built-in PHP web server. This provides a convenient way to test a Laravel
// application without having installed a "real" web server software here.
if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/html'.$uri)) {
    return false;
}

require_once __DIR__.'/html/index.php';
```

I find this solution a lot simpler than messing around with you htaccess. You also ensure all of the Laravel core files cannot be accessed from a url.

**Other issue you are having (Internal pages)**

This is probably due to your apache not allowing override with Laravels htaccess

Go to the command line of your server and access the apache2.conf file

```
cd /etc/apache2
```

Open the apache2.conf file with nano

```
sudo nano apache2.conf
```

Now locate the following

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Change this to

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Writeout the changes and exit nano.

Restart apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

It should now be working :)

Answer (score 1):

To only match the homepage, i.e. `http://domainxyz.com/` you need to match the empty path (as mod_Rewrite removes the leading `/`.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domainxyz.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /view.php?page=process/ [NC,L]
```

Comment: Hi, I don't use for example `/view.php?page=process/` my framwork, My issue is see `website.com` with this `website.com/ any word /index.php` url.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website.com/([a-zA-Z-]*)/index.php [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.website.com/([a-zA-Z-]*)/index.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.website.com [L,R=302,NC]
```

Make sure you clear your cache before testing this. You will notice I've used `R=302`, this is a temporary redirect. If the redirect works and you're happy with it, then switch that to `R=301` which is a permanent redirect.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for help me but Don't work this code :-(

Comment: My files are this route: `/var/www/html`.

Answer (score 1):

This code worked for me. It will remove extention from your website e.g .php and all. Try it once.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Hi, I have add this code to `public/.htaccess` or '.htaccess` in root ?

Comment: you can add this in both places. but public/.htaccess is what I suggest.

Comment: Thank you for help me :-), I overwrite this code in `public/.htaccess`. This code is true but now i can see website with `website.com/public` :-(

Comment: Put this code into your root .htaccess file 

    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ public/index.php [L]